# Return a list of modified list pairs

Tags: python

Given my_list below with a list of list pairs, how do I create a new list where common element[0] values would have a list for their respective element[1] values? The order does not matter of elements from the main list does not matter.

Example

```
my_list = [['color', 'red'], ['length', 2], ['color', 'blue], ['shape', 'circle'], ['shape', 'square']]

return [['color', ['red', 'blue']], ['shape', ['circle', 'square']], ['length', 2]]
```

Comment: Dict would fit here perfectly. Are you sure that you need list of pairs in my_list instead of dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to use a default dict for that, if you do not mind about the order of the keys.

```
my_list = [['color', 'red'], ['length', 2], ['color', 'blue'], ['shape', 'circle'], ['shape', 'square']]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for sublist in my_list:
    d[sublist[0]].append(sublist[1])
print(d)
```

And if you absolutely want it as the list you specified

```
answer = []
for key in d:
    if len(d[key]) == 1:
        answer.append([key, d[key][0]])
    else:
        answer.append([key, d[key]])
print(answer)
```